# How to increment a dereferenced double pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

In code I would typically use:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void dref1(char **blah)
{
    (*blah)[0] = 'a';
    (*blah)[1] = 'z';
    (*blah)[2] = 0x00;
}

/* or */

void dref2(char **blah)
{
    char *p = *blah;

    *p++ = 'w';
    *p++ = 't';
    *p = 0x00;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *buf = malloc(3);

    dref1(&buf);
    puts(buf);
    dref2(&buf);
    puts(buf);
    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is if it is possible / how to dereference and increment pointer directly:

```
**blah = 'q';       /* OK as (*blah)[0] ? */
(*blah)++;          /* Why not this? */
*((*blah)++) = 'w'; /* ;or. */
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can. Just test a litter. I think you have the idea.

The problem with using `blah` the way you write, is, that when you come back to main, not only the content of the buffer is changed (correctly as you whant), but the pointer `buf` itself too. That may be not what you want, and definetivily not what you need to free.

Test:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void dref1(char **blah)
{
    (*blah)[0] = 'a';
    (*blah)[1] = 'z';
    (*blah)[2] = 0x00;
}

/* or */

void dref2(char **blah)
{
    char *p = *blah;

    *p++ = 'w';
    *p++ = 't';
    *p = 0x00;
}

void dref3(char **blah)
{
    *(*blah)++ = 'w';
    *(*blah)++ = 't';
    *(*blah) = 0x00;
}

void dref4(char **blah)
{
    **blah = 'q';       /* OK as (*blah)[0] ? */
    (*blah)++;          /* Why not this? */
    *((*blah)++) = 'w'; /* ;or. */

}


int main(void)
{
    char *buf = (char*)malloc(3);
    char *buf1=buf;
    dref1(&buf);
    puts(buf);
    dref2(&buf);
    puts(buf);
    dref3(&buf);
    puts(buf);
    puts(buf1);

    buf=buf1;
    dref4(&buf);
    puts(buf);
    puts(buf1);

    free(buf1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Just realized it myself :). That was the issue. It is so dang obvious once I realized what I was doing.

Comment: Test a litter of what, dude?

Answer (score 15):

I don't know what your real intent is, but it seems to me that you need to learn the difference between `*p++` and `(*p)++` as expressions.

The first expression dereferences the pointer and advances the pointer itself, not the value that is being pointed to.

The second expression dereferences the pointer and modifies the pointed-to value by applying the postfix `++` operator. Whether the pointed-to value is a pointer or simply an integer doesn't matter.

This has to do with the precedence of the unary `*` operator and the postfix `++` operator. In the absence of parentheses, the `++` operator is applied first and its result is used as the operand of the `*` operator.

EDIT:

Assuming that `blah` is of type `char **`, here is a list of the possible operations and what each one would do:

- Obviously, `blah` yields a value of type `char **`;
- `*blah` yields `char *`;
- `**blah` yields `char`;
- `*(*blah)++` dereferences `blah` to get a `char *`, and then the `*p++` analogy comes.
- `**blah++` dereferences `blah` twice to get the pointed-to value and then increments the `blah` pointer.
- `(**blah)++` dereferences the `blah` pointer twice, and then the `(*p)++` analogy comes.

Comment: Note that `**blah++`  is increasing the address of `buf` which is a stack address in this case, assign value to `blah` in next statement may crash the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's nothing wrong with the `dref1`.

`(*blah)[0] = *(*blah)+0 = **blah`

so you can write `(*blah)[0]='a';`

There is no point in doing `(*blah)++;` You are simply incrementing and losing the address returned by `malloc`.